# Как соединить 2 таблицы PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно соединить 2 таблицы.
таблица 1

---

```
select  
fv.flight_no as "a_number"  
, fv.arrival_city as "a_arrival_city"  
, a.coordinates as "a_coordinates"  
from bookings.flights_v fv  
inner join  
bookings.airports a  
on a.city = fv.arrival_city  
limit 1
```

---

**город прибытия/    номер рейса/    координаты города прибытия**

Якутск          PG0243        (129.77099609375,62.093299865722656)

и аналогичная таблица 2

---

```
select  
fv.flight_no as "d_number"  
, fv.departure_city  as "d_departure_city"  
, a.coordinates as "d_coordinates"  
from bookings.flights_v fv  
inner join  
bookings.airports a  
on a.city = fv.arrival_city  
limit 1
```

---

**город отправления/     номер рейса/   координаты города отправления**

Санкт-Петербург     PG0243    (129.77099609375,62.093299865722656)

При использовании подзапроса выводится ошибка "subquery must return only one column"
При использовании with, при соединении выходит ошибка  syntax error at or near "with"

Нужно чтоб была одна таблица
номер рейса
, город отправления
, город прибытия
, координаты города прибытия
, координаты города прибытия

структура БД https://github.com/cnegaa/air_transportation/blob/main/structure/structure_bd.jpg

Answer (score 0):

А что вы хотите дополнительно соединять? вот так?:

```
select  
  fv.flight_no as "a_number"  
  , fv.departure_city  as "d_departure_city"  
  , a.coordinates as "d_coordinates"  
  , fv.arrival_city as "a_arrival_city"  
  , b.coordinates as "a_coordinates"
from 
  bookings.flights_v fv  
  inner join bookings.airports a on a.city = fv.d_departure_city
  inner join bookings.airports b on b.city = fv.arrival_city  
limit 1
```

Comment: большое спасибо, все работает)